# Obtain needed Kronecker products from output of Eigensystem[]

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

`Eigensystem[M]` gives a list of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the square matrix `M`, i.e.

```
{{val1,val2,...},{vec1,vec2,...}}.
```

I need a routine that will produce the Kronecker product of each eigenvector with itself, e.g. `KroneckerProduct[vec1, vec1]`, `KroneckerProduct[vec2, vec2]`, etc.
And, in addition produce the Kronecker product of each eigenvector corresponding to degenerate eigenvalues, e.g. if

```
val2 == val3 == val4
```

produce

```
 KroneckerProduct[vec2,vec3]
 KroneckerProduct[vec2,vec4]
 KroneckerProduct[vec3,vec4]
```

and do this for as many degeneracies as there may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first and easy part of the question:

```
es = Eigensystem[{{{a, 0, 0, 0}, {0, a, 0, 0}, {0, 0, b, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
      a}}}]
```

> {{a, a, a, b}, {{0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}}}

```
m1 = KroneckerProduct[#, #] & /@ es[[2]];
TeXForm[MatrixForm /@ m1]
```

> $\left\{\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\right\}$

For the second part:

```
m2 = KroneckerProduct @@@ # & /@ 
 (Subsets[#, {2}]&/@Select[GatherBy[Transpose[es], First][[All, All, 2]], Length@# > 1 &])
TeXForm[m2]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

In versions 10+, you can use `GroupBy`

```
m2b = Select[Length@# > 1 &] @ Values @ 
  GroupBy[Transpose[es], First -> Last,  KroneckerProduct @@@ Subsets[#, {2}] &]
m2b == m2
```

> True